# Views Ajax error with jquery 1.8

Tags: views, javascript

I'm using Bxslider which required jquery 1.8 to be responsive. However, when using jquery 1.8 I get errors with views when trying assign and change values.

[image]

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: are you not using the https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update module?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that module. jquery 1.7 doesn't give me the errors. I've found another person who is in the same situation.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21812930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the 7.x-2.x-dev version of jquery allowed me to select version 1.5 of jquery for administrative pages and solves my problems.